# Parsing a date using Jquery Templates

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

So, im using Jquery templates to render a table, with some user comments, and i need some guidance on how to call a function on my date member

my template code is :

```
       <script id="approvaltmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <table class="table table-user-information" id="approveScroll" style="height:100px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved by"></i> ${UserName}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span id="approvedDate"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="approved date"></i> ${AuditDate}</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </script>
```

with this being using to loop over my data:

```
success: function (msg) {

                    $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                        //alert(item.UserName);
                        $('#approvaltmpl').tmpl(item).appendTo('#results');
                    });
                }
```

I need to call a function on the date, as it's a none iso format coming back:

[image]

the function i need to call is:

```
     function parseJsonDate(dateString) {
            return new Date(parseInt(dateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
        }
```

i've also noticed that the tool tips dont work using this method either.

So, how do i call the function, and how do i get the tool tips to work?

Comment: like this return new Date(Date.parseInt(dateString.replace('/Date(', '')));?

Comment: C-Link, i tried calling the method from within the template, so i'm not sure this will work. Plus, where exactly are you suggesting that this is called?